# Getting selection of structs from an array of structs in BQ

Tags: sql, data-structures, google-bigquery

I have a table where one column is defined as:

```
my_column ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value FLOAT64, description STRING>>
```

Is there some easy way how to specify list of parameters to be returned in a `SELECT` statement? For instance removing `description`, so the result column would be still an array of structs but containing only `key` and `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this way:

```
SELECT
ARRAY(SELECT AS VALUE STRUCT(key, value) FROM a.my_column) as my_new_column
FROM my_table a
```

No joining or unnesting needed.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(description)
    FROM UNNEST(my_column)
  ) AS my_column)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Above fully preserves schema of table and only does change in my_column field by removing description

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail. Works as always. :) Although, I found a slightly neater solution in a meantime. I will be selecting that as accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

I would just unnest and then re-aggregate your selected fields.

```
select array_agg(struct(m.key,m.value)) as my_new_column
from table
left join unnest(my_column) m
```

Comment: I am getting error `Cannot query rows larger than 100MB limit.` with this solution.

Comment: That says something about your table/data, and nesting/unnesting might not be appropriate.